# Can’t left align multiple equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath

There are already numerous questions on this subject on tex.SE, but although I tried them I can’t seem to be able to get left alignment working on a system of equations.  Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    a = x\\
    b = x*y
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

What’s wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

You're misusing `align`. This environment produces pairs of columns (most often just two are used) one right aligned and one left aligned.

Subsequent pairs have the same behavior and `align` leaves a space between the pairs, so that the available space is equally divided (including the overall left and right spaces).

It's not really clear what you mean by “left aligned”. If you want your equations left aligned at a fixed distance from the margin, then the `fleqn` option to `amsmath` will do it for you.

However, in cases like yours, the = signs are also usually aligned. So you have some options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{align}
a &= x \\
b &= xy \\
ccc &= xyz
\end{align}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\begin{align}
&a = x \\
&b = xy \\
&ccc = xyz
\end{align}
\lipsum[3][1-3]

\end{document}
```

In the second example, the first column is skipped and the equations are aligned at their left margins. I added a longer left-hand side just to better see the difference.

[image]

In case you want `fleqn` (fixed length from margin equations), you can dispense with the leading `&` in the second case, using `gather`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{align}
a &= x \\
b &= xy \\
ccc &= xyz
\end{align}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\begin{gather}
a = x \\
b = xy \\
ccc = xyz
\end{gather}
\lipsum[3][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Which kind of alignment to use, with respect to =, depends on several factors and there is no fixed rule encompassing all cases. In general, I only align at = equations that are strongly related to one another, but it's my way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the `&` character used to select the alignment position :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    &a = x\\
    &b = x\,y
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Note that it can be used at multiple positions, but in principle the usage is to arrange a table of equations.  As a consequence the expressions will stick to odd-positionned `&` and flush from even-positionned `&`.  So if you want e.g. to align at the beginning of the equation and before the `=` you have to double the `&` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    &a &&= x\\
    &b &&= x\,y
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Also note that the `&` is not needed if you just use the `amsmath` `gather` environment together with the `fleqn` option (the whole system won’t be centered, though) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
    a = x\\
    b = x\,y
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: did you look at the output from this at all???? The `align` example makes completely unreadable output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for pointing this, I adapted from a largest example where it seemed to work but must have missed something.  I updated the answer.